# How to get quotas of AWS EC2 via boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm working on boto3 - SDK python for AWS.

How can I get AWS Service Limits via boto3 library like bellow:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html

Answer (score 3):

Some of those limits can be queried through [EC2.Client.describe_account_attributes()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=describeaccountattributes#EC2.Client.describe_account_attributes)

> `describe_account_attributes(**kwargs)`
>
> Describes attributes of your
>   AWS account. The following are the supported account attributes:
>
> ...
>
> - `max-instances` : The maximum number of On-Demand instances that you can
>     run.
> - `vpc-max-security-groups-per-interface` : The maximum number of
>     security groups that you can assign to a network interface.
> - `max-elastic-ips` : The maximum number of Elastic IP addresses that you
>     can allocate for use with EC2-Classic.
> - `vpc-max-elastic-ips` : The
>     maximum number of Elastic IP addresses that you can allocate for use
>     with EC2-VPC.

Comment: Thanks, but not all? I want to get all of quotas :D

Comment: You can check that [awsLimitChecker](https://awslimitchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) uses `EC2.Client.describe_account_attributes()` to [obtain the limits that are available through this API](https://github.com/jantman/awslimitchecker/blob/master/awslimitchecker/services/ec2.py#L264) and uses hardcoded values for the rest of the limits.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [awsLimitchecker](https://awslimitchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? 
I use it to create a report every morning and send it to a slack group, where I monitor our current limits. Works really well.

Comment: That's great! Let's me try it. Thanks.

Comment: For sure, its open source as well so you can learn all the inner workings from the code.

Comment: If you find out the tool I've suggested fits your use case, please check my answer as correct.

Comment: Ok, I have not yet test it.

Comment: the docs on it are really bad in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

There is a better option than *awsLimitChecker*, as not all AWS Service Instances' Quota can be retrieved through it, for example for many EC2 instances you need to use [TrustedAdvisor service](https://awslimitchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limits.html#ec2) and many EC2 service instances' quota could not be retrieved at all. Also recently AWS has changed the on-demand service quota EC2 instance based limits to vCPU based limit, categorized as follows:

- Running On-Demand Standard (A, C, D, H, I, M, R, T, Z) instances  ->  1152 vCPUs
- Running On-Demand F instances   ->   128 vCPUs
- Running On-Demand G instances  ->  128 vCPUs
- Running On-Demand P instances  ->  128 vCPUs
- Running On-Demand X instances ->  128 vCPUs

Another approach to retrieve service quota is using [boto3's Service Quota client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/service-quotas.html). You can use APIs like [list_service_quotas](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/service-quotas.html#ServiceQuotas.Client.list_service_quotas) to retrieve complete list of service quotas support by an aws service (*ec2*). Or for specific service quota you can use [get_service_quota](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/service-quotas.html#ServiceQuotas.Client.get_service_quota). Additionally to use above mentioned APIs make sure to add [service quotas actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/2019-06-24/apireference/API_Operations.html) (policy) into IAM user / group.

Following is source code snippet.

```
import boto3

map_quota_codes = {}
client = ''

def get_service_quota(self, quota_name):
    """
    Retrieves requested AWS service quota.
    :param str quota_name: Full name of Quota e.g. Running On-Demand Standard (A, C, D, H, I, M, R, T, Z) instances
    """
    if not map_quota_codes or quota_name not in map_quota_codes:
        return {}

    quota_code = map_quota_codes[quota_name]["QuotaCode"]
    res = client.get_service_quota(ServiceCode = 'ec2', QuotaCode = quota_code)

    return res["Quota"]

if __name__ == "main":

    # AWS account login should be done here.
    client = boto3.client('service-quotas')
    service_quota_resp = self.client.list_service_quotas(ServiceCode = 'ec2')

    # this is required to map get correct quota code for respective ec2 service quota.
    for quota in service_quota_resp['Quotas']:
        map_quota_codes[quota["QuotaName"]] = {'QuotaCode': quota["QuotaCode"]}

    while "NextToken" in service_quota_resp:
        service_quota_resp = client.list_service_quotas(ServiceCode = 'ec2', NextToken = service_quota_resp["NextToken"])

        for quota in service_quota_resp['Quotas']:
            map_quota_codes[quota["QuotaName"]] = {'QuotaCode': quota["QuotaCode"]}
```

End Note: If you like the description and my answer helped you Upvote it and mark it as an answer. thanks

jack